# AS3 Misunderstanding

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I need help... Why my object doesn't  spawn where I tell him but always in the same place?

```
 package Classes  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class sy_player extends Sprite{

        public function sy_player(skin:int,startX:int ,startY:int):void {

            this.x = startX;
            this.y = startY;

        }
        }
    }
```

In the Main class:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {


    public function Main() {
        var player:sy_player = new sy_player(0,100,300);
        addChild(player);


    }
}
```

Comment: what is this "same place"? `x=0,y=0`?

Comment: yes it is... x=0 , y=0

Comment: From the few lines you gave us, there is no reason for your object to spawn at 0,0. I've just executed your code, and the Sprite spawns correctly at 100,300. Can you give us more data ?